# Can Codeigniter hmvc supports multiple controllers from a module?

Tags: codeigniter-3, hmvc

I am new to codeigniter hmvc . I have created a module folder called Hod under folder modules. In Hod module folder I have created controllers and views folders.In views folder i have two files called hod_welcome.php and pmo_welcome.php. Under controllers folder I have created two controller files called Hod.php and Pmo.php.

```
class Hod extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('hod_welcome');
    }

}
//this is pmo.php file code
class Pmo extends MY_Controller
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->view('pmo_welcome');
        }

    }
http://localhost/ci_hmvc/hod - working
http://localhost/ci_hmvc/pmo - it is saying 404 - pagenot found
I am using Codeiniter 3.1.9
```

Where I am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.